# RecyclerView jerks while scrolling up when children vary in height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

My UI consists of a RecyclerView that shows text entries in TextViews. The implementation isn't really complex, the ViewHolder stores the textView in a field, and `onBindViewHolder` just calls `TextView.setText` on it.

```
private List<String> entries;

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TextHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.textView.text = entries[position];
}
```

When the entries are short, there is no problem. However, when some or all the entries are long (like 2 or 3 times the length of the screen), it causes sudden jerks when scrolling back up, which I find really jarring. It's doesn't seem like a lag, the RecyclerView just scrolls smoothly, then immediately jumps upwards. It happens both when I flick and when I drag slowly.

Does anyone know causes this, and is here a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an element in a RecyclerView adapter has a certain view type, the RecyclerView will also assume it has a consistent height.  This will cause the RecyclerView to lose it's tracking when scrolling.

I've worked around this by assigning a different `ViewType` to different-sized elements when overriding `getItemViewType` in the adapter.  This will work if your items are varying in height, but otherwise consistently displayed.

Another thing you could try is resetting the child view's `LayoutParams` in the `onBindViewHolder()` method of the adapter.  That may cause it to refresh the parent layout and be notified of the child's updated state.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! The different view types method worked like a charm!